# Bluetooth permanent discoverability not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

From the [Android API Guide > Bluetooth > Enabling discoverability](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html):

> The maximum duration an app can set is 3600 seconds, **and a value of 0 means the device is always discoverable**. Any value below 0 or above 3600 is automatically set to 120 secs). For example, this snippet sets the duration to 300:

So I want to make the device always discoverable, and use their code snippet:

```
 Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
 discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
 startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

While the snippet correctly shows the user a dialog that asks their permission to make their device "always visible to other bluetooth devices", pressing "Yes" will only make the device discoverable for 120 seconds.

Is this a bug? What can I do about it? I'm testing on API 17, with a Samsung Galaxy S2.

**Edit:**

[Extend Android Bluetooth Discoverability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906737/extend-android-bluetooth-discoverability)

Here it is suggested in one of the answers that this goes beyond Android, and that this issue has to do with the `DiscoverableTimeout` value in `/system/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Is this true? If so, how would I edit the value?

Comment: Why do you want it discoverable for longer than a few minutes?

Comment: Does that matter? I just want to use the mentioned functionality, whether that's advisable or not.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite late for the party , but still for someone who might need this.
Maximum you can make device discover able is only for 300 seconds.
As per following docs:

```
public static final String EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION

Added in API level 5
Used as an optional int extra field in ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE intents to request a specific duration for discoverability in seconds. The current default is 120 seconds, and requests over 300 seconds will be capped. These values could change.

Constant Value: "android.bluetooth.adapter.extra.DISCOVERABLE_DURATION"
```